# WebGl Object literal not working

Tags: javascript, webgl

The basic issue is that I can't get my example to work in Object literal - and I don't get any errors in the console so I am not reayll sure why it doesn't want to run.

I know that the code works if I just use some normal functions and not Object Literal notation so maybe I have messed up the scope somewhere or should I use Object Constructors?

I had a look around and couldn't see any issues relating to using WebGl within an Object Literal so presume I have some dodgy coding going on.

I have submitted a jsfiddle for you to inspect - please ignore the cross domain issue of the texture.

http://jsfiddle.net/j6RMD/

```
        var MyCube = {

            container : null,
            renderer  : null,
            scene     : null,
            camera    : null,
            cube      : null,
            animating : null,
            light     : null,
            mapUrl    : null,
            map       : null,
            material  : null,
            geometry  : null,
            animating : false,

            onLoad : function(){
                this.container = $("#container");

                this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );

                this.renderer.setSize(this.container.offsetWidth, this.container.offsetHeight);
                $(this.container).append( this.renderer.domElement );

                this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

                this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45,
                this.container.offsetWidth / this.container.offsetHeight, 1, 4000 );
                this.camera.position.set( 0, 0, 3 );

                this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5);
                this.light.position.set(0, 0, 1);
                this.scene.add( this.light );

                this.mapUrl = "molumen_small_funny_angry_monster-999px.png";
                this.map    = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(this.mapUrl);

                this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: this.map });

                this.geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);

                this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

                this.cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 5;
                this.cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 5;

                this.scene.add( this.cube );

                this.myrun();
            },

            myrun : function(){
                MyCube.renderer.render(MyCube.scene,MyCube.camera);

                if(MyCube.animating)
                {
                    MyCube.cube.rotation.y -= 0.11;
                    MyCube.cube.rotation.x -= 0.10;
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(MyCube.myrun);
            }

        }

        MyCube.onLoad();

        $('#container').click(function(){
            MyCube.animating = !MyCube.animating;
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Solved at last - thanks for nothing Stackoverflow!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add [0] onto the end of the jQuery selector for the container div like so...

`this.container = $("#container")[0];`

and not

`this.container = $("#container");`

What I had failed to realize (stupidly) was that without the [0] I was returning a jQuery object and not a html dom element. Considering the wealth of knowledge on here I'm surprised no one spotted this before me.

If you go back to my jsfiddle example and just add in the [0] you will see everything works (apart from the texture).

I think this post is the single best example of how something so simple can hold you up for such a long time...sigh!